# Does the Nokia Ovi suite work?

Tags: smartphone

Please tell whether Nokia Ovi suite works on Ubuntu. I searched a lot not but have not been able to find the answer.

If not please provide me with some other alternative.

Comment: what do you normally use the Ovi suite for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is **no official support** by Nokia.

I'd recommend to use the **Ovi Suite via dual boot** into Windows/Mac.

---

But there is also a project currently in development:

http://series60-remote.sourceforge.net/index.php?module=Content&func=view&pid=8

[image]

Comment: Its Nokuntu. Unofficial Nokia Pc Suite for Linux

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OVI Suite from my Ubuntu 12.04 (and 10.04 before that) in a WindowsXP Virtualbox. It works fine after giving Virtualbox access to bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

S60 Remote as well as Nokunto, Gammu/Wammu and Xgnokii are all a waste of time as it doesn't really work.  I am using a seto of sulutions that will most definately help you.  Read here https://askubuntu.com/captcha?s=c4d2a716-1e69-4e5b-b62a-fadf4809020c

I summarize the system integration, which is easy enough to set up:

***On the Computer***

1. OS - Linux
2. Email via Thunderbird (which also works on Windows)
3. Calendar via Lightning add-in for Thunderbird
4. Zindus add-in for Thunderbird - contacts sync
5. Provider for Google Calendar = add-in for Thunderbird & Lightning

***On the Phone - Android or Symbian***

1. Emoze email suite
2. Setup your Google accounts up as AlwaysOn/Push

You can always still sync your Gmail contacts via your phone's own sync app, which is what I am doing.  I am using Nokia's own email and synced contacts with Google but I sync my calendar via Emoze.  It works better on my Nokia E63 and it also uses less battery this way.

I have been using Nokia ever since 1995 but will now switch to Samsung as their Android phones co-habitate more seamlessly with Linux and offer more solutions.  Nokia did not see the need to develop for us Linux users and painted themselves into a corner, sadly.  Their phone hardware remains the best, I suppose.

I have used other contacts sync plugins for Thunderbird but found them to be lacking when compared with the Zindus app. gContactsync, if I recall the name correctly, is inconsistent and complicated.

Follow the links on my posts as well.  Always add or suggest alernatives if you have found a better solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't according to the documentation in wine (which is not an emulator but runs windows program on linux) [OviSuiteWine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10164)